# C# MongoDriver Lookup

Tags: c#, mongodb

Im trying to do lookup on my mongo collections.

I have a collection called wishlists and collection named wishes.

Each wish has reference to wishlist called wishlistId.

Im trying to get all wishlists with its wishes for the user with id = userId.

Here is my query (wishlistService.GetAll()):

```
return this.collection.Aggregate().Match(Builders<WishlistModel>.Filter.Where(o => o.userId == userId)).Lookup("wishes", "_id", "wishlistId", "result").ToListAsync();
```

When I look at the result using debugger it has the correct data somewhere inside it, but when im trying to return this as Ok result, it will fail.

```
var userId = User.Identity.Name;
List<BsonDocument> wishlists = await this.wishlistsService.GetAll(userId);
return Ok(wishlists);
```

The error in Angular http request is:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/wishlists net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

This is what I see in debugger when viewing wishlists variable.
[image]

Im sure Im doing something wrong when querying the data, but im not sure what as im new to .NET

Comment: So `wishlists` has the right data in it? If so it doesn't sound like you have a problem with mongodb...

Comment: @Chris Ive added a screenshot from debugger. Data are there in the array. From the error it looks like serialization during Ok() is failing.

Comment: @Chris I did output the wishlists[0].toJson() to the console and it threw error for each function on that object you can see in the screenshot. So I assume similar error is thrown during serialization when Ok(wishlists) is called. This means I have to return data from service without this object methods ( which should not be there in the first place )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of fiddling Ive found the correct way to do this.

You have to set up the strict mode for JsonSerializer.

```
var jsonWriterSettings = new MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonOutputMode.Strict };
```

and then serialize the results from the service in controller.

```
return Ok(wishlists.ToJson(jsonWriterSettings));
```